# MATLAB Pre-Allocate structure with String / Datetime fields slows code down considerably

Tags: string, matlab, memory, memory-management, struct

I am trying to read through and sort two large .txt files, around 300 mb at the largest.
Originally, for each line of code I read, I would re create the matrix like this

```
strarray.full = [strarray.full ; new_info]
strarray.newdate = [strarray.newdate ; new_info ]
```

This slowed down considerably once the files reached around 20 mb.  I've seen that Pre Allocating matrices prevent MATLAB from having to re create the growing matrix each iteration.  So now I have the following:
strarray.newdate =  NaT(2000000,1);
strarray.full = strings(2000000,1);

where I have a counting variable ' j ' that counts each time something should be added into the matrix.
strarray.full(j,1) = new_info;
strarray.newdate(j,1) = new_info;

When I did this, the code slowed down considerably, both starting off slower and slowing down faster as time progressed.  After running a profiler, it says that nearly all the time is spent putting the info into the pre-allocated matrix.

I cant attach the .txt files directly so I have to strip it down here.

.txt Format 1:

```
Datetime1 ~ *string* ~ *string* ~ *string*
               *string*
Datetime1 ~ *string* ~ *string* ~ *string*
               *string*
               *string*
               *string*
               *string*
Datetime1 ~ *string* ~ *string* ~ *string*
               *string*
               *string*
```

.txt Format 2:

```
datetime2 ~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~*~
datetime2 ~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~*~
datetime2 ~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~~~ *string* ~*~
```

Thanks.

EDIT2:  Here is the first section:

```
%% Finding the Directory

format compact
MyFolder = input('Please specify a folder:\n','s');
% Check if valid path
while ~isfolder(MyFolder)

    fprintf('\nError: This folder does not exist: Please try again:\n')

    MyFolder = input('\nPlease specify folder:\n','s');
end
% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
% FilePattern = fullfile(MyFolder,'*Console*.txt');
% BaseFiles = dir(FilePattern);
AllFileCheck = dir(fullfile(MyFolder,'**/*.*'));

%% Reading the files from the directory
% Reading each of the files from TheFiles
tic
FileList = [];
% stripping files to just *console*.txt
for k=1:length(AllFileCheck)

    name = fullfile(AllFileCheck(k).folder,AllFileCheck(k).name);
    
    if AllFileCheck(k).isdir == 0  && contains(name,'.txt')  && contains(name,'Console','IgnoreCase',true)
       % is a file and if it has both 'console' and ".txt" in its str name
       FullFileName = fullfile(AllFileCheck(k).folder, fullfile(AllFileCheck(k).name));
       % fprintf('File: Now reading %s\n', FullFileName);
       PlaceHoldPathFix = string(FullFileName);
       FileList = [FileList;PlaceHoldPathFix];
    else
        % If its a folder isdir == 1...
    end
end
```

EDIT:  Here is some of the code.

```
N = 2000000;
full = strings(N,1);
newdate =  strings(N,1);

TraceDatePat = '\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d.\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\.\d\d\d';
traceform = 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS';
newform = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS';
LogDatePat ='\d\d\d\d\ \d\d\ \d\d\ \d\d\ \d\d\ \d\d\.\d\d\d';
Logform = 'yyyy MM dd HH mm ss.SSS';
newform = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS';
j = 0

for k=1:length(FileList)
    if contains(FileList(k),'trace','IgnoreCase',true) % TRACE ERROR
        fprintf('READING TRACE File: %s\n',FileList(k))
        filler = '';
        fid = fopen(FileList(k));
    toc
        while ~feof(fid) % pulls TRACE files and their timestamps
            Dcheck = fgets(fid);

            if Dcheck == -1
                continue
            end
            
            if ~startsWith(Dcheck,'[');
                filler = append(filler, Dcheck);
            else
                j =  j+1 ;
                full(j) = filler;
                
                % resetting filler
                filler = Dcheck;
                datecurrent = regexp(filler,TraceDatePat,'match');
                newdate(j) = string(datetime(datecurrent(1),'InputFormat',traceform, 'Format', newform));
            
            end  
        end
        j = j+1
        full(j) = filler;
        filler = '';
        fclose(fid); % close the current file
        
    elseif contains(FileList(k),'Log','IgnoreCase',false) % LOG FILES
    fprintf('READING LOG File: %s\n',FileList(k))
%     filler = [];

    fid = fopen(FileList(k));

    while ~feof(fid) % pulls LOG files and their timestamps
        Dcheck = fgets(fid);
        j = j+1;

        full(j) = Dcheck;
        
%         full = string(full);
        datecurrent = regexp(Dcheck,LogDatePat,'match');        % V down there, I added DateCurrent(1) b/c some lines have more than one date
        datefill = string(datetime(datecurrent(1),'InputFormat',Logform, 'Format', newform));
        newdate(j) = datefill;
    
    end
    fclose(fid);    
   
    else % error message
        fprintf('\n\nSOMETHING WENT WRONG\n\n')
    end
end
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what the question is, i.e. are you just wanting to confirm this is expected behaviour, explaination on why it is slowing down or are you looking for how to do this another way that is considerably faster?

Comment: I was looking mainly for an explanation of why its so slow and wanted to know if there were any extra paths that could be taken to fix this.  I have figured out part of it, now its just inputting the new data into the  "datetime" array that is slowing the code down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track!

I think the problem is that the fact that your `string` array is inside the field of a struct, instead of being a plain local variable, is defeating Matlab's "in-place update" optimization, so it's actually copying the entire array each time you update it, undoing your attempt to preallocate it. Compare these two similar operations:

```matlab
>> n = 20000;
>> tic; str = "foo"; strs = strings(n,1); for i = 1:numel(strs); strs(i) = str; end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.009908 seconds.
>> s = struct;
>> tic; str = "foo"; s.strs = strings(n,1); for i = 1:numel(s.strs); s.strs(i) = str; end; toc
Elapsed time is 4.801056 seconds.
>>
```

Instead of having `newdate` and `full` be fields on a struct, instead make them regular local variables in your function, and only assign them to fields in the struct at the end of your function once they're fully populated. Then it should be fast.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

This seemed to fix one my original problem so thank you! But now it seemed to create a new one.

Running a profiler again showed that it takes effectively no time to input the " full' variable now.

But now its taking even longer for a separate section of the code:

newdate(j,1) = datetime(datecurrent(1),'InputFormat',traceform, 'Format', newform);

For this script, I need to scan each line and re arrange some of the dates and then put it into my newdate variable.

Why would this now become an issue?

Comment: I ran an extra test, it looks like the main issue with the above line is not the datetime function itself, but putting the modified date into the "newdate" array.  Right now I have this defining the pre allocated array.
N = 2010000
full = strings(N,1)
newdate =  NaT(N,1);

Comment: Hmmm. Any chance you could share your full code and sample files so I could test it myself? Maybe in a GitHub repo, or a cut-down version pasted here? And what version of Matlab are you running?

Comment: I added the section of the code that has all of the loops in it.  It got a bit messy.

Frustratingly, I am not allowed to share any of the sample files...

I am using Version 2019b.

I kept doing some tests, the datetime function itself is definitely causing the problem.  I ran a 2000 second test, and around 1800 of the seconds were spend on the datetime function itself.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that's going to take me a while to review. My first advice is to try to restructure your code so you can pull the `datetime` call up out of the loop: the time that `datetime` spends detecting the format of the dates it processes is a per-call penalty. If you can buffer up all those dates as strings first, and then do a single `datetime()` conversion at the end of the loop, it'll probably run a lot faster. Or you could explicitly pass the `InputFormat` option to it to tell it what format to use and skip the cost of auto-detection.

Comment: I've reported the "in-place-modification optimization gets defeated when array is inside struct" issue to MathWorks Support; case #04362626. I'd suggest you report this to them too (email support@mathworks.com); the more users that bring up a problem; the more likely it is to get fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew!  I will get started on that right away!  I will also reach out to the mathworks support team as well.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey Brabec! I tried your example code, but it's erroring out with `FileList undefined` for me. Could you try to narrow this down to a full self-contained example?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I've updated the code so it should be able to run now.  More importantly, I ran some more tests on the bulk vs per line datetime function.  With only 161 lines of date strings, it took 0.23 secs for per line and 0.005 seconds for a bulk call.  Your totally right, this ended up speeding things up considerably. Thank you so much!  I never would have thought that was the problem!

Comment: I got the run time down to 100 secs for a 300MB test case.  The general process was:  Call Regexp to get strings with OG date formats and put all forms into a Xx1 string array>  Call datetime()  once for each date format the array, so output will be a new array for each format > convert all new arrays back to string arrays>  Call Cellfun() on each new array to replace <missing> spots with empty ' ' strings.  Append() all of the new arrays back into one array with all of the newly formatted dates.

I can't say this enough but thank you so much Andrew, I couldn't have done this without you!